# Filed expression with in operator in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a SSRS report where I need to show a new expression called Region

If CountryName = Dubai,Kuwait,Iran,Iraq then I need to show Region as  'MiddleEast'
If CountryName= Nigeria,Egypt,Ethiopia then I need to show Region as 'Africa'
If CountryName= India,Pakistan,Srilanka then Region as 'Asia'

Please help how to create calculation filed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a simple way to do this in SSRS. I would use the SWITCH statement instead of an IIF to handle the multiple possibilities cleaner.

Since you're searching for multiple choices, I use use the INSTR to search for the Country in a list for that Region.

```
=SWITCH(InStr("Dubai,Kuwait,Iran,Iraq", Fields!COUNTRY.Value) > 0, "Middle East", 
        InStr("Nigeria,Egypt,Ethiopia", Fields!COUNTRY.Value) > 0, "Africa", 
        InStr("India,Pakistan,Srilanka", Fields!COUNTRY.Value) > 0, "Asia", 
        1 = 1, "Other")
```

This will check for The country field in the list of names for each InStr function - returning the character position if found or 0 if not. Then it compares this to 0 and if it is greater, returns the Region.

The 1 = 1 is like an ELSE for any that don't match.

It may be better to make a Calculated field in the dataset rather than putting this in an expression.